# DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [404] flutter login not working

Tags: flutter, api, dio

I'm a student who new to flutter. I'm creating a login page using flutter and node API. But when I give login details it throws error `DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [404]`and display snack bar "Something went wrong..." line. Below I have mentioned the code I have created for integrating API. how should I correct this. Postman Request is working properly as image showing.

it would be great if someone can correct my code. appriciate your help on this.

```
//api integartion

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String email = "";
  String password = "";

  Future LoginData() async {
    try {
      var response = await Dio().post(BASE_API + '/user/Login',
          data: {"email": email, "password": password});

      if (response.data["data"] == "logged in successfully") {
        Get.snackbar("success", "Welcome");
        Get.to(HomeScreen());

      } else {
        Get.snackbar(
          "error",
          "No User Found",
          backgroundColor: heartRed.withOpacity(0.8),
          colorText: textWhite,
        );
      }
      print("res: $response");
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("Error", "Something went wrong.Please contact admin",
          backgroundColor: textWhite.withOpacity(0.5),
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: textGrey,
          colorText: textGrey,
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.error_outline_outlined,
            color: heartRed,
            size: 30,
          ));
      print(e);
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(
        child: Container(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Email",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: textGrey, fontFamily: "Dubai", fontSize: 14)),
                  validator: (String? UserName) {
                    if (UserName != null && UserName.isEmpty) {
                      return "Email can't be empty";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onChanged: (String? text) {
                    email = text!;
                    print(email);
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Password",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: textGrey, fontFamily: "Dubai", fontSize: 14)),
                  validator: (String? Password) {
                    if (Password != null && Password.isEmpty) {
                      return "Password can't be empty";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onChanged: (String? text) {
                    password = text!;
                    print(password);
                  },
                ),
                remberMeCheckBox(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                      child: Text(
                        "Forget Password",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: textGrey, fontFamily: "Dubai", fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Get.to(ForgetPassword());
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: ButtonM("Login"),
                    onTap: () async {
                      await LoginData().then((value) {
                        print(value);
                      });
                      LoginData();
                      //Get.to(HomeScreen());
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 404 means `not found` which usually means the url is wrong. Make sure `BASE_API` does not en with a `/`. Or maybe `/Login` needs to be lower case?

Comment: thanks yes a extra slash /.. thank you